# Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module '@react-native/normalize-color'

Tags: xcode, react-native

I just wanted to try react-native.However, after run the script "npm run ios",I got this error in the Xcode's simulator.

[image]
react-native version: v0.66.0,
platform: Mac OS Big Sur 11.6.2,
How can I fix this?

Comment: Please share any relevant code [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) by editing your Question. Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Comment: Did you use react-native-maps?

Answer (score 11):

install '@react-native/normalize-color' using command line `npm i @react-native/normalize-color`

Comment: Sorry,It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Kevin's answer works if you're using older version of react-native like me.

Answer (score 9):

Try installing '@react-native/normalize-color@2.0.0' if you are using 'react-native-maps'. This worked for me. It's probably because we may be using an older version of 'react-native' which included an older version of 'normalize-color'.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I was using react-native 0.66.4